# Invariants of Lie superalgebras

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, invariant-theory, lie-superalgebras

Let $V=V_0 \oplus V_1$ be a $\mathbb Z_2$-graded vector space over $\mathbb C$. Suppose $V$ has an even non-degenerate bilinear form $(-, -)$
which is symmetric on $V_0$, skew symmetric on $V_1$, and satisfies
$(V_0, V_1) = (V_1, V_0) = 0$. The orthosymplectic Lie superalgebra $\mathfrak{osp}(m,2n)$ is the subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(m,2n)$ defined by $\{X \in \mathfrak{gl}(m,2n): (Xv,w)+(-1)^{|X||v|}(v,Xw)=0\}$. Let $W=V^{\otimes k} \otimes V^{*\otimes l}$.

Then what is a spanning set for the space of tensor invariants $(W)^{\mathfrak{osp}(m,2n)}$ ?

Like in the orthogonal and symplectic Lie algebra case here also I believe that we must have $k=l$ and then the spanning set is indexed by the elements of the symmetric group $S_{2k}$. I checked the translated version of A. Sergeev's paper on classical invariant theory of Lie superalgebras but didn't find a concrete statement. A statement or a reference in this direction will be highly appreciated.